# why can't android system webview load HTML5 page?

Tags: android, html, webview

I want to use WebView to load the URL "https://xwpx.eduyun.cn:7001". But I found that if the version of **Android System Webview** is higher or equal to 64, the webView works fine. However, if the version is lower than or equal to 60, there will be compatibility problems with HTML5. (Note: I did not test the 61-63 version). Can anyone please help to answer this question, thank you!

Comment: Have you use  webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

Comment: Yes, I tried, but it didn't work。

Comment: Use [Remote Debugging](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/) of [WebView](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/webviews/) to see what is incompatible.